# Trouble with epstopdf: File 'foo-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found

Tags: epstopdf

My question has been asked before but none of the answers previously has answered my question. I have an `.eps` file that I want to include in my LaTeX document. For this purpose I have included the epstopdf package. However, when I try to compile my document by using pdflatex, I get the error message `File 'foo-eps-converted-to-pdf' not found`. In the log file it says:

```
{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2]
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <Aoo.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2014-04-28 18:54:16
(epstopdf)                    size: 18858 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <foo-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf --outfile=foo-eps-converted-to.pdf foo.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 142.
runsystem(epstopdf --outfile=foo-eps-converted-to.pdf foo.eps)...disabled.

Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <foo-eps-converted-to.pdf>.

! Package pdftex.def Error: File `foo-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation. Type  H
<return>  for immediate help.  
...                                    

l.142 \includegraphics{foo.eps}
```

It should be noted that all files are in the same directory, so there shouldn't be any issues with that.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The important line of the `.log` file is:

```
runsystem(epstopdf --outfile=foo-eps-converted-to.pdf foo.eps)...disabled.
```

The conversion do not work, because the shell escape feature is not enabled.
Probably you are using an older TeX distribution. TeX Live and MiKTeX have a the restricted shell escape feature enabled by default.

On older systems (not too old, of course) the following option should work:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape
```

or (MiKTeX)

```
pdflatex --enable-write18
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I tried it, but unfortunately it didn't work. I also got the same line that you quoted in the log file. My TeX system is probably not too old; I downloaded it in 2012.

Comment: Which TeX distribution and version do you use? Any message on the console about `unrecognized option '-shell-escape'`?

Comment: It worked now! I was stupid enough to write "pdflatex filename --shell-escape" rather than "pdflatex --shell-escape filename" the first time. What does, in fact, "-shell-escape" do?

Comment: To answer your question, I use TeX Live 2009 for Debian.

Comment: `-shell-escape` allows the execution of external programs. In this case the program `epstopdf` converts the EPS file to PDF, which is then included.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem on a Mac and it gave me a real headache. The following helped me

In my log file I had:

```
runsystem(epstopdf --outfile=foo-eps-converted-to.pdf foo.eps)...executed
```

I was however told that:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libXt.6.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gs
Reason: image not found
```

and so subsequently:

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `foo-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.
```

Turned out to be a problem with upgrading to Yosemite where X11 is moved from usr/X11 to opt/X11. I found another post about this which recommended manually adding a link:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/X11 /usr/X11
```

For me this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue on my Mac with macOS 10.12. Apple is not including X11 anymore, which is required for epstopdf. You need to download it at https://www.xquartz.org After that, all my eps files just run smoothly.

Comment: Could you perhaps describe a little more how to install it?  As it stands it is more of a "link-only" answer, which are discouraged on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody else stumbles upon the same error message.
In my case the issue emerged from the file path of the `*.eps` file referenced in the `*.eps_tex` file, since I had all my pics in a separate subfolder called `pics`.

Changing

```
\put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{foo.eps}}
```

in the `foo.eps_tex` file to

```
\put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{pics/foo.eps}}
```

solved the problem.

Maybe this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

On Texmaker 5.0.3 (compiled with Qt 5.11.3), changing compiler to XeLateX made the trick for me:

```
xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with eps to pdf conversion. The log shows the error message as "file not found". I figured that the issues were with the figure name. It has a blank space in the name (for instance `bus voltage.eps`). The problem was solved when I changed the figure name to `busVoltage.eps` by deleting the blank space.

The error also pops up if the figure path has blank space in it. It's better to avoid blank spaces with `_`.

I hope this helps.