# unable to add eps file in pdf created by latex

Tags: epstopdf

I am trying to attach .eps file in my pdf document created by Latex. I am using windows winshell 3.3.2.6 (windows 7). I following packages \usepackage{graphicx}, \usepackage{epsfig},
\usepackage{epstopdf}. I get the error -  Error: Package pdftex.def Error: File `contents/images/16-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found. finally pdf document created just writes the file name at the location where file is to be inserted. Kindly help me to put .eps image in pdf file.

Comment: You need to look in the `log` file to see exactly what is happening. A common problem is that shell escape is not enabled. Answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174068/2417) may help.

Comment: (a) If the file name appears, then option `draft` is active. (b) The package `epstopdf` is a wrapper for the external program `epstopdf`, which is a wrapper for ghostscript. Shell escape (also restricted) needs to be enabled to run the external program `epstopdf`. In TeX Live, there is a line near the beginning of the `.log` file (`restricted \write18 enabled`).

Comment: Have you tried to compile using `graphics` and `latex` instead of `pdflatex`?