# when include eps to texshop, why is there automatically generated a convert-to-pdf file

Tags: pdf, eps

I'm compiling a report using mac texshop and I want to add an eps. picture. I just don't understand whenever I use the following command

```
\usepackages{graphicx}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphic{picture}
\end{figure}
```

a `picture-eps-convert-pdf` is automatically generated.

I'm sure I'm using Latex.

I really don't like this automatically generated file and it slow the speed a lot.So is there anyone can help me just let Textshop accept eps? Thank you.

Comment: The PDF files are generated only once, so it won't slow down the next LaTeX runs, provided you don't remove them. Don't worry.

Comment: If you compile your document using LaTeX+dvips the files are not created.  Add `% !TEX TS-program = latex` to the first line of your document.

Comment: @AlanMunn It truly works, thank you very much! But I'm just wondering I'm using Latex at the very beginning, why do I still need "...= latex"?

Answer (score 5):

The default mode of TeXShop is using `pdflatex` for producing the final output.

Nowadays (almost) nobody uses DVI as the final format, but PDF. Sometimes DVI files are used as intermediate steps (particularly if PSTricks is necessary). When there's no need for a DVI file (as intermediate step or as final format) it's faster to output directly to PDF; take also into account that Mac OS X can display DVI files only via XQuartz and the display won't necessarily reflect the real output (for instance when TikZ is used in the document).

The problem with `pdflatex`<sup>1</sup> is that it can't load EPS graphics; this has raised innumerable questions in forums and mailing lists. The solution is to convert the EPS files to PDF. Since a couple of years, `pdflatex` has been able to do the conversion by itself, so one can even say that `pdflatex` *can* load EPS graphics, now!

The loading of an EPS file, say `figure.eps` happens in this way:

- if `figure-converted-eps-to.pdf` exists, check whether its timestamp is more recent than the timestamp of `figure.eps`; if so, input it.
- if `figure-converted-eps-to.pdf` doesn't exist or is not more recent than `figure.eps`, call the utility `epstopdf` to make a new `figure-converted-eps-to.pdf`, then input it.

*No* user's intervention is needed!

As a consequence, if you don't modify the EPS files nor remove the generated PDF files, the conversion will take place just once, so it won't slow down LaTeX (really `pdflatex`) runs later on.

<sub>1. Like in Alfred Hitchcock's “The Problem with Harry”, people were very worried about the ‘issue’, which at the end was solved by making the boy (re)discover the dead body ‘today’, as he's not really knowledgeable about yesterday/today/tomorrow. In the present case, if the PDF version of the EPS doesn't exist, it's created and everybody's happy, unless creation date happens to be earlier than the corresponding EPS: in this case, the file is converted anew.</sub>

Comment: I had a related problem and found this answer, but implementing your answer has not solved my problem, which is that I keep getting the error message "! Package pdf.tex.def Error: File figure-eps-converted-to.pdf not found". I should say that when I manually converted the .eps file and named it figure-eps-converted-to.pdf, then it would correctly load the file.

Comment: I wonder if I'm not loading some necessary package or checking some necessary box in my TeXShop preferences...

Comment: @LeeMosher I've just tried for being sure: a simple document with a single `\includegraphics{file.eps}` works flawlessly. Can you try running `pdflatex` from the command line?

Comment: Ah, I found the solution elsewhere: [the latest Mac systems do not include XQuartz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375622/95520).

Comment: I installed that and now it works.

Comment: @LeeMosher I guess you needed ghostscript.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by Alan Munn in his sub-comment, paste the below text as the first line of your document:

```
% !TEX TS-program = latex
```