# epstopdf package converts a file, and pdftex package doesn't find it

Tags: pdftex, epstopdf

I'm using texmaker on OSX. After upgrading my OSX to El Capitan, I couldn't do anything in texmaker at first because the .tex file would not be found. I fixed the problem strictly following [this guide](http://srcport.com/articles/7/145/how-to-fix-mactex--texmaker--latex-on-el-capitan-mac/).
Now everything works, except for when I want to include a .eps file in the `\includegraphics` environment. Then I get the error message:

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File 'figure_overview-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.
```

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=1.25\textwidth]{figure_overview}}
\caption{Single-parameter sweep overview}
\label{1parsweep}
\end{figure}
```

The log file says this:

```
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <figure_overview.eps>
(epstopdf) date: 2016-02-25 14:04:24
(epstopdf) size: 220121 bytes
(epstopdf) Output file: <figure_overview-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf) Command: <repstopdf --outfile=figure_overview-eps-converted-to.pdf figure_overview.eps>
(epstopdf) \includegraphics on input line 85.
runsystem(repstopdf --outfile=figure_overview-eps-converted-to.pdf figure_overview.eps)...executed safely (allowed).
Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <figure_overview-eps-converted-to.pdf>.
! Package pdftex.def Error: File 'figure_overview-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.
```

(line 85 is the one with the `\makebox` and `\includegraphics` command)

So apparently, in contrast to the problem described in
[Trouble with epstopdf: File 'foo-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174068/trouble-with-epstopdf-file-foo-eps-converted-to-pdf-not-found) 
my `epstopdf` package seems to work fine but it stores the file somewhere (I don't know where and I have no idea how to find that out), but `pdftex` is looking for the file somewhere else (I don't know where, either... how can I find that out?). How can I fix this?

If I convert the eps-file to a pdf-file manually and save the respective pdf in the Figures folder, it works. But I want to use .eps files and convert them on the fly, as this gives better results and is easier.

My preamble is:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work with the command `\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./Figures/}`.

Comment: Now I get pretty much the same error message: 

`! Package pdftex.def Error: File './Figures/figure_overview-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.`

Comment: Maybe it would help to know where `pdftex` is looking for the output file from `epstopdf`, as well as where epstopdf puts the output file, and then make both directories the same in the texmaker settings, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Try moving your graphics file in the same directory as your `.tex` file and commenting out both the commands `\graphicspath{}` and `\epstopdfsetup{}`. Do you see the `.pdf` file now?

Comment: I didn't see them. However, a colleague just fixed the problem by entering `/Library/TeX/texbin/` in the line which says "Add to PATH" in my texmaker preferences. We both are not entirely sure why this works, but it does. 

Thanks for your help, anyway!